# read-only files on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

when trying to delete file, I got the rm command on ubuntu page at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeletingFiles. And on, this page I got the term **read-only** files. I have tried to google **read-only file linux**, but cannot find any definition about this. Could you tell me what read-only mean? Does it mean all owner, group and other have only read permission? Thank you!

Comment: It means for the user accessing, you don't have write permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Does it mean all owner, group and other have only read permission?

They may have different permissions. But you (the current user) have only read permission.

Answer (score 2):

Linux has three kind of permission for user, group and others.

1. **r**: read permission
2. **w**: write permission
3. **x**: execute permission

If the file is read-only, it means you (the user) don't have the **w** permission on it and so you cannot delete the file.

Use:

`chmod +w FILE`

To add that permission. You can change files permission only if you're the owner of the file.

Otherwise, you can remove the file using `sudo`, gaining super user privilege.

`sudo rm FILE`

It will prompt you for a password and it will works only if you're in the `/etc/sudoers/` file (and you're likely to be there if you're the only user, since you're using Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

A read-only file is a file that you don't have permission to alter its content. To see detailed info about your permissions use `ls -l`; if you want to change the permissions, use `chmod`. Also see [this example](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/chmod/) for better understanding.

Answer (score -6):

Change the Permissions with `chmod` or try with sudu:

`sudo rm file.xxx`

Comment: definitely don't run the above command as it'll just remove the file